# how to improve performance in analysing log file using mapreduce

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce

We have to analyze the log files using hadoop as it can handle large data easily. So, I wrote one piece of mapreduce program. But even my mapreduce program is taking lot of time to get the data.

```
String keys[] = value.toString().split(" ");
        int keysLength = keys.length;
        if(keysLength > 4 && StringUtils.isNumeric(keys[keysLength-5])) {
            this.keyWords.set(keys[0]+"-"+keys[1]+" "+keys[2]+" "+keys[keysLength-5]+" "+keys[keysLength-2]);
            context.write(new IntWritable(1), keyWords);
        }
```

The **requirement** is, we will have mostly 10 to 15 of .gz files and every .gz file have one log file inside. we have to pull the data from that log file to analyze it.

**Sample input in the log file**:

> 2015-09-12 03:39:45.201 [service_client] [anhgv-63ac7ca63ac] [[ACTIVE]
>   ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
>   INFO  TempServerImplementation - || Server: loclhost  121.1.0.0 |
>   Service Category: Testing | Service Method: add | Application Id: Test
>   | Status Code: 200 | Duration: 594ms ||

So could someone help me how can I tune up the performance.

Thanks
Sai

Comment: You could process the files concurrently.

Comment: Please give me extra informations ? Every .gz files size are equal ? If yes,  how many mb ?

Comment: @pckmn, every .gz will be unique and the size is around 50MB.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Could you please explain me in more specific way, as an example.

Comment: Create an ExecutorService of say a fixed size which is the number of CPUs you have. Add a task to this pool for each file to process that file. This way you can process multiple files concurently.

Comment: @PeterLawrey they will already be processed concurrently in his current implementation. The issue is that you can't split `gz` files and so the entire of each file will have to be be processed in the same process, whether it be by a mapper or an `ExecutorService`. You don't need to implement your own threading etc in MapReduce.

Comment: You can use faster options for compressing the data such as using the faster compressor for GZIP or Snappy compression.  The down side is that it won't compressed the data as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, we can use the compressing technique. But the problem here is again for compressing it is taking lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SPARK(We can think this as in memory map reduce), it is 10x to 100x faster than traditional Map reduce. Please check trade-offs between hadoop map-reduce and SPARK before using.

Comment: have an idea. but still checking with the examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways you can speed up your job, **input size** and **variable initialisation**.

**Input Size**

`gz` is not a splittable format. That means that if you have 15 input `gz` files, you will only have 15 mappers. I can see from the comments that each `gz` file is 50MB, so at a generous 10:1 compression ratio, each mapper would be processing 500MB. This can take time, and unless you've got a <15 node cluster, you'll have nodes that are doing nothing. By uncompressing the data before the MR job you could have more mappers which would reduce the runtime.

**Variable Initialisation**

In the below line:

```
context.write(new IntWritable(1), keyWords);
```

you're generating a big overheard by allocating a brand new `IntWritable` for each output. Instead, why not allocate it at the top of the class? It doesn't change, so it doesn't need allocating each time.

For example:

```
private static final IntWritable ONE_WRITABLE = new IntWritable(1);
...
context.write(ONE_WRITABLE, keyWords);
```

The same applies to the strings you use - `" "` and `"-"`. Assign them as static variables also and again avoid creating fresh ones each time.

Comment: Thanks Ben, It's my fault actually. I tried it by changing as you said, but it hasn't changed the execution time.